# Backend api call not working in Vue(front)

Tags: api, vue.js

My environment

- front - windows, port 3000
- backend - linux (ubuntu) in docker container, port 5000

Vue(front) tsconfig.json

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

front api call code

```
const response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/login?email=" + code);
```

backend(Nestjs) - main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(5000);
}

bootstrap();
```

I expect the api call to go to the backend, localhost:5000

but i get a 404 error

When I tried with postman, I got normal return, but when I sent the request using axios in Vue with the same request, I got 404 not found.

The most incomprehensible thing is that with the current settings, it was normally requested when developing in the past.

I don't know how to fix this

please help a lot

Repositories currently being edited: https://github.com/PracticeofEno/ft_transcendence

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg... I send POST message..
But api is GET Message

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).